# I cannot fix EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in Swift xcode 8.1 on Json

Tags: ios, swift

I am studying the swift and I update the xcode to current version (8.1). So the source that I saved was changed. When I ran the code. It cracked and I cannot fixed it. It showed "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on the last line. This is a code that I have studied from web.
Thank you very much.

```
let urlString = "http://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response:URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if let responseData = data {

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)

        if let dict = json as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let name = dict["name"] as? String, let height = dict["height"] as? String, let birth = dict["birth_year"] as? String, let hair = dict["hair_color"] as? String {

                let person = SWPerson(name: name, height: height, birthYear: birth, hairColor: hair)

                print(person.name)
                print(person.height)
                print(person.hairColor)
                print(person.birthYear)

                if let films = dict["films"] as? [String] {
                    for film in films {
                        print(film)
                    }
                }

            }
        }


    } catch {
        print("Could not serialize")
    }
  }
} as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) .resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save much time if you simply read the documentation

- Press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> (zero, not O)
- Type *dataTask*, select `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` and press *return*.

You will get

> ```
> func dataTask(with url: URL, 
>      completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
> ```

Do you see the slightly difference in the `error` parameter?

So the correct syntax in your code is

```
session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response:URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
...
}).resume()
```

There is no type cast at the end.

Further the type annotations in the completion block are not needed because the compiler infers the types. The error doesn't occur if you just write

```
session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
...
}).resume()
```

The shortest form is using the trailing closure syntax

```
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
...
}.resume()
```